# Removing the .htm From Items in a PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays

How can I remove the .htm from the end of each of the items in an array? I'm very new to PHP, so as specific help as possible would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my script:

```
<?PHP

    $myDirectory = opendir("pages/");

    while($entryName = readdir($myDirectory)) {
        $dirArray[] = $entryName;
    }

    closedir($myDirectory);

    $indexCount = count($dirArray);

    sort($dirArray);

    for($index=0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) {
            if (substr("$dirArray[$index]", 0, 1) != "."){ // don't list hidden files
            print("<a href=\"index.php?p=$dirArray[$index]\">$dirArray[$index]</a>/n");
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the string is not guaranteed to always have `.htm` at the end, running the string you want to modify through the following function should work for you:

```
$str = preg_replace('/\.htm$/', '', $str);
```

Comment: It should always have the .htm at the end, but I'll try this.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) (to iterate over the array) and [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) (to return just the filename portion minus the extension).

This will work with any filename extension.

```
$dirArray = array_map(function($item) {
    return pathinfo($item, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
}, $dirArray);
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/LBzxZl).

The anonymous function is a >= PHP 5.3 thing. Just use a named function if using an older version.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your code with iterators. Here's an example:

```
foreach (new DirectoryIterator('pages') as $fileInfo) {
    if ($fileInfo->isFile()) {
        $name = $fileInfo->getBasename('.htm');
        print("<a href='index.php?p=$name'>$name</a><br>");
    }
}
```